Worm plots - application for GAM
Recently, I stumbled upon the application of a "worm plot" for model diagnostics. It was new, for me, kind of way of looking at model residuals. For those not familiar with what a worm plot is ut us a de-trended QQplot. I originally stumbled upon it in the gamlss R-package (wp(...)) then later found a version in the gratia R-package (worm_plot(...)).
Here is an example plot from the gamlss::wp(model).

Driven by my curiosity after running the function and learning more about the plot in the literature (see von Buuren and Fredriks (2001)) I started to dig into the gamlss::wp(...) code (like a pig after truffles) to learn more. The "u" shaped dashed lines are essentially the confidence interval of a normal distribution (correct me if I'm wrong)
The code looks something like this ...
level <- 0.95
z <- seq(-4,4,0.25)
p <- pnorm(z)
se <- (1/dnorm(z))*(sqrt(p*(1-p)/length(qq$y)))
low <- qnorm((1-level)/2)*se
high <- -low

plot(...)
lines(z, low, lty=2)
lines(z, high, lty=2)

The gratia package gives us a couple of different options including a "normal" and a "simulated" method to generate the QQ statistics and reference bands. Here is an example of the "simulated" method for a model that uses a tweedie distribution. The code is pretty simple gratia::worm_plot(model,method =  "simulate").

So I guess my question, specific to this example, is would it be better to generate the QQ theoretical vs residual from the specific distribution specified in the model? In this case it would be a QQ from a Tweedie distribution. Similarly, for the reference bands would a confidence interval based on a Tweedie distribution be better (i.e. the dashed "u" lines in the 1st plot)?
I've started to explore this but not sure

Is appropriate or worth going into this much detail?

Is "simulated" reference band good enough given the data and model?


How to correctly estimate the theoretical quantiles from a Tweedie distribution

I've gotten close but keep getting hung up on how best to estimate a qtweedie distribution (example below).


(Still haven't gotten to this but just started thinking about it) The math associated with estimating confidence intervals from a Tweedie distribution.

Start of an example to make a tweedie-specific QQplot
library(mgcv)
library(tweedie)
library(statmod)

# Example data
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n)
y <- rtweedie(n, mu = 5 + 2 * x, phi = 1, power = 1.5)

# Fit a GAM with Tweedie distribution
gam_fit <- gam(y ~ s(x), family = tw())

# Calculate the residuals
residuals <- residuals(gam_fit, type = "response")

# Generate theoretical quantiles
predicted_values <- predict(gam_fit, type = "response")

theoretical_quantiles <- qtweedie(ppoints(n), 
                                  mu = predicted_values, 
                                  phi = ???,
                                  power = ???)



IIRC phi would be the dispersion parameter in mgcv's formulation, which you get as gam_fit$scale, while the estimated power can be accessed using gratia::theta(gam_fit). The simulation based band is much better than assuming the residuals are Gaussian; the theory doesn't dictate that the residuals be distributed Gaussian and often a very far from it. See the help for qq.gam() in mgcv for a link to a paper on this.

@GavinSimpson Thanks for being so helpful! I understand and appreciate the simulated reference band. What if the reference band is based on the distribution used in the mode? In the case above (1st plot), what if the "u" shaped lines are referencing a Tweedie rather than a normal/gaussian distribution? Would it be useful or is better/same information gained from the simulated reference band? ... as usual, I'm overthinking things.
